# Add a server between router and switch (production)

Tags: networking, routing

I have a small office network basically like below, there are more router/pc connected in S1. As you can see, the router is doing job of DHCP, DNS. but now I wish to add a Linux server between R1 and S1, So I can monitor the network traffic and do other more advance server admin stuff.

the whole office network is 192.168.1.x and people are using their computer everyday. What network configuration should the new Linux server have (both interfaces) in order to minimize the changes need in the network?

tried to change R1 ip to 192.168.100.1 them add the server with FE0/0 192.168.100.1 and FE0/1 192.168.1.1 
but looks cannot ping the original Router..

[image]

Comment: Does the modem know that it needs to send packets bound for 192.168.1.177 to 192.168.1.1? If not, you need to add a static route to the modem. (Or better yet, set the modem to bridge mode and use the server as the router.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would design the Linux machine to be a [transparent Squid bridge](http://teklimbu.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/running-a-transparent-linux-squid-bridge/) that merely passes Layer 2 traffic.

This is also heavily dependent on what "more advance server admin stuff" you want to do. Will you be mangling packets in-transit? Then you'll have to make iptables rules as appropriate. Are you going to be filtering traffic based on content? Some DPI magic will need to be done, and the appropriate packages installed.

A layer 2 bridge will keep the interference on the network to a minimum. Just make sure you have a third interface with a Layer 3 address on the network or a serial connection for remote out of band administration.

Comment: The whole squid for simple bridging?

Comment: @Kondybas Squid brings with it a lot of potential for extensibility based on what a person wants. The OP mentioned "more advance server admin stuff" so at least the platform will be there for him should he need it. However, yes, there are lighter weight possibilities.

Comment: that looks exactly what I need!, well later I wish to filtering traffic based on content (p2p, video streaming etc), MAC address filtering (only registered MAC can access the network) and register bandwidth usage (who,how long, total MB, and kb/s used). will squid suit for me?

Comment: @Kossel You have a lot of requirements but I think squid can do each of them. Squid is amazing. =)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this but I would suggest using one of the Linux firewall distros. I personally use Smoothwall Express (installed on an old PC) but there are others to choose from. Such a system will give you what you require, as well as a good firewall.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, can it set like a transparent bridge mode so i don't have to reassign ips?

Answer (score 0):

You need a bridge, containing both your interfaces. It must be a transparent bridge, passing through everything including ARP-packets.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind the best choice you can go for it a http://www.vyatta.com/ .

If you know any cisco config, these will be a breeze and there is so much documentation. It is completely free and light weight and can have squid running on it and run DNS/DHCP.

It also lets you do any NATing you might want to do and you can add another firewall to your network.

The best thing about vyatta's is that there so simple to set up in a virtual environment (XenServer).